# Zookeeper, do watches on nodes that are modified block all the other reads?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, watch

My understanding of ZooKeeper is that a client will always execute requests in an ordered manner from ITS point of view.

Therefore if the client 1 issues:

- write node A
- 2 reads node A, B
- write node B
  they will be executed in that order.

But in case client 1 has also a watch on a node C, and client 2 writes that node, does that write on node C impacts/blocks reads from client 1?

For example:

- Client 1: starts watching C
- Client 1: writes node A
- Client 2: writes C
- (Client 1: does client 1 block until the watch of C is fired? What if at this point the Client 1 tries to write node C?)
- Client 1: 3 reads node A then B then C
- Client 1: writes node B

Answer (score 0):

> But in case client 1 has also a watch on a node C, and client 2 writes
>   that node, does that write on node C impacts/blocks reads from client
>   1?

It doesn't *block* reads from client1 because (check [here](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.6/zookeeperProgrammers.html#ch_bindings)):

> When a ZooKeeper object is created, two threads are created as well:
>   an IO thread and an event thread. All IO happens on the IO thread
>   (using Java NIO). All event callbacks happen on the event thread.

but *impacts* client1 with thee see of events in this order (check [here](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.6/zookeeperProgrammers.html#sc_WatchGuarantees)):

> A client will see a watch event for a znode it is watching before
>   seeing the new data that corresponds to that znode.

Next question was:

> Does client 1 block until the watch of C is fired?

No (see the explanation above).

> What if at this point the Client 1 tries to write node C?

It will overwrite client2's write because it happens *after* according to your bullets sequence ([ZooKeeper is ordered](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.6/zookeeperOver.html#sc_designGoals); check also [here](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.6/zookeeperOver.html#Implementation) in order to understand how ZooKeeper achive the ordering).